# DataStax Astra Backups - what's the backup policy, how long are they retained, and how to restore a backup?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, database-backups, datastax-astra

We're migrating a Cassandra database to Datastax Astra (serverless, PAYG service). I'm curious about how backups work.  From https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/manage/db/manage-multi-region.html it seems that backups are automatically created but restoring a backup requires opening a support ticket.

Is anyone aware of any further documentation regarding backups and Astra DB other than the above link?  Can I set a backup policy (e.g how frequently are full snapshots taken vs deltas).  Is it possible to download snapshots and are these reverse compatible with Cassandra?

It would be great if it was possible to view available backups and restore a backup directly from the Astra database portal website.

Comment: What's [the DB ID](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/astra-faq.html#_where_do_i_find_the_database_id_and_organization_id)?

Comment: could you answer the above?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the question about Astra!

First, [**Astra DB**](https://www.datastax.com/astra) is a fully-managed serverless DBaaS.

Backup and Restore information / documentation is available [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/plan/planning.html#backup-restore) and based on that and as of this writing,

> *Serverless databases created using Astra DB are **automatically** backed up once an hour. The hourly backups are stored for 20 days...*

at no extra charge. A restore operation at this point requires one to work with the DataStax Support team (as of this writing).

As far as the other items are concerned, e.g. self-service backup restore (or) scheduling additional backup at extra cost, they're on the roadmap. If you would like to discuss about this, please go ahead and raise a ticket [here](https://support.datastax.com/) or [talk to your account representative](https://www.datastax.com/contact-us) and someone will be able to reach out to discuss these needs with you and your team.

*Full Disclosure*: I work at DataStax (as of this writing).

Comment: thanks for your post.  The "here" documentation link points to this post.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for pointing that. I've fixed it now. I've asked a question about the [DB ID](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/astra-faq.html#_where_do_i_find_the_database_id_and_organization_id) - could you answer that?

Comment: Hi @Madhavan the DBID is e978ce30-2873-4a1f-bccd-cb98f322737b